# Energy norm/ Proof of the axiom of the norm

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, sobolev-spaces

Let $u\in H^1_0(a,b)$(Sobolev space), $p\in C^1[a,b], r\in C[a,b]$, with the latter two being strictly positive.

It is known that: $\Vert u \Vert_{\mathscr A } = \left[\mathscr{A}(u,u)\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}=\int_a^b\left[ p(x)\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2 + r(x)\left(u(x) \right)^2\,dx  \right]^{\frac{1}{2}}$. This is the definition of the energy norm.

I would like to prove that:
If $\Vert u \Vert_{\mathscr A } = 0\Rightarrow u = 0 $ in $H^1_0(a,b)$

Comment: Do you have conditions on the signs of $p$ and $r$? Are they both strictly positive?

Comment: Sorry, yes both are strictly positive.

Comment: Can't you just observe that the integrand must be 0 almost everywhere, and since both terms in the integrand a re non-negative, they each must be 0 almost everywhere? Then, it follows directly that the same is true for $u$?

Comment: I think that's right, that sounds like a good argument. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! For the sake of closing the question and removing it from the queue, I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\|u\|_\mathscr{A}=0$, we must have that the integrand $(p(u')^2+ru^2)^{1/2}=0$ almost everywhere. This further implies that $p(u')^2+ru^2=0$ a.e. Since $p,r>0,$ we must have that each individual term in that sum is $0$ a.e., and in particular $ru^2=0$ a.e. Once again referring to the sign of $r$, we conclude finally that $u=0$ a.e.